# Where to get aws-access-id and aws-secret-key for uploading amazon web service application?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Recently I was trying to upload an app to aws but an error occurred:

ERROR: The current user does not have the correct permissions. Reason: Operation Denied. The security token included in the request is invalid.
You have not yet set up your credentials or your credentials are incorrect 
You must provide your credentials.
(aws-access-id):
(aws-secret-key): 
ERROR: Operation Denied. The security token included in the request is invalid.

I was wondering where to get aws-access-id and aws-secret-key for this step in order to upload the app successfully.

Comment: Just a side note, your question is poorly composed, it is too specific and yet it does not contain all the necessary information to answer it. Other than that it looks as you haven't spend enough efforts to investigate the problem yourself and expecting that someone will spend those 2 minutes for you. In general people won't do that and you won't get the answer you were looking for. So please invest your time and efforts in to your questions, it will primarily help you to obtain the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved.

It turns out that the Access Key ID and Access Key can be found on:
https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#/security_credential

Comment: That was usefull, the page in the documentation is wrong.